# Need to parse onenote content using nodejs

Tags: node.js, onenote

I have onenote file and I want to parse contents using nodejs.

I tried to use Microsoft graph API but there no way it provided to locate our onenote file. it uses onenote.run api when I try to use in mycode it throws error as onenote module is not there

Comment: Please provide your coding snippet.

Comment: I used fs module fs.readFile(`filename.one`) { if (err) throw err; var data = data.toString('UTF8`) console.log(data) i am getting log in unreadable format

Comment: Is it possible to read onenote file using Fs module ?